# Xamarin Forms Views from DependencyService

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working with an app created with Xamarin Forms, which includes projects for iOS and Android, in addition to the shared project.
I have created the view in the shared project using XAML.
The problem is that for accessibility issues I need to send an `AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUSED` event to a label after updating its value in order for the screen reader to verbalize it, and I have not found a way to do it in the shared project.
Now I'm trying to do it using DependencyServices, but I don't know how to access the label from the service that implements the interface in Android.
In summary: I would need to access a label created by Xamarin Forms from the Android or iOS project.
Could someone give me some help?

Comment: If you want to access the label which created in Forms from specific platform , it would be better to use `Custom Renderer` . Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/ .

Comment: Hi.
Your comment helped me a lot, I achieved what I was looking for by combining CustomRenderers with MessagingCenter to communicate between the viewmodel and the customrenderer. Thank you!

Comment: You could share your answer , or I can post it with more details and you can accept it, which will help more people :)